# Base64 to Bitmap to display in ImageView

Tags: android, json, bitmap

I have this code which get BLOB image that is already converted to string using webservice. This is the JSON output.

```
{driver_name: "Anna Biendia"
 taxi_plate_no: "NUV 900"
 driver_contact_no: "09169271825"
 driver_operator: "grab"
 driver_operator_address: "987 Buendia St. California"
 image: "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAACDQAAAXcCAYAAADXlEzmAAAACXBIWX..."}
```

This is my code in android which get the JSON and display it in the layout. The other values have been displayed except for the image.

```
public class DriverDetails extends Activity {
ArrayList<Objects> objectsList = new ArrayList<>();
String url = "http://192.168.1.110:8080/taxisafe3/displays/taxidetails";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_driver_details);

    new Task().execute(url);
}
public class Task extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String content = HttpULRConnect.getData(url);
        return content;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        try {
            TextView title1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            TextView title2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
            TextView title3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);
            TextView title4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView11);
            ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

            JSONArray ary = new JSONArray(s);
            for (int i = 0; i < ary.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonobject = ary.getJSONObject(i);
                Objects objects = new Objects();
                objects.setDriver_name(jsonobject.getString("driver_name"));
                objects.setTaxi_plate_no(jsonobject.getString("taxi_plate_no"));
                objects.setDriver_operator(jsonobject.getString("driver_operator"));
                objects.setDriver_operator_address(jsonobject.getString("driver_operator_address"));
                objects.setDriver_contact_no(jsonobject.getString("driver_contact_no"));
                objects.setImage(jsonobject.getString("image"));
                objectsList.add(objects);


                if (title1 != null){
                    title1.setText(objects.getDriver_name());
                }
                if (title != null){
                    title.setText(objects.getTaxi_plate_no());
                }
                if (title2 != null){
                    title2.setText(objects.getDriver_operator());
                }
                if (title3 != null){
                    title3.setText(objects.getDriver_operator_address());
                }
                if (title4 != null){
                    title4.setText(objects.getDriver_contact_no());
                }
                if(image != null){
                    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(objects.getImage(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                    Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
                    image.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
}
}
```

What is wrong in my code why the image doesn't display in ImageView? Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After convert the **base64** to **bitmap**

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(objects.getImage(), Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```

**resize your bitmap to Imageview height and width**

```
image.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(decodedByte, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), false));
```

Comment: sir I tried your code but the application has stop. this is what i've done.

Comment: <code>byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(objects.getImage(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                        Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
                        image.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(decodedByte, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), false));<code>

Comment: mmmm code is work good with me , debug your code step by step using log to know when and where the crash happens

Comment: Sir. thank you very much. i misunderstood your comment. :) i already did it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your image is missing height and width?

try using

```
// resize bitmap
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 720, 720, true);
```

u can use 720x720 just to see if that's the problem, if it is, you can pass the desired height & width instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir. But when i added your code below the Bitmap decodedbyte and i change image.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap). But when i run the app, it unfornately stop.

Comment: does the size of my ImageView be the same with the size of my image?