# Issue in Covert from String Base64 to Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, base64

**Code stuff for convert from `Bitmap` to `String Base64`**

```
Bitmap thumbnail = extras.getParcelable("data");
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
thumbnail.recycle();
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
String attachment = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

**Code stuff for convert from `String Base64` to `Bitmap`**

```
byte[] encodeByte = Base64.decode(strBase64, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

but i get `bitmap = null;`

I also refer [Base64 to Bitmap to display in ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30964027/base64-to-bitmap-to-display-in-imageview)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show your encoding code, you are decoding it correctly

Answer (score 1):

```
  // convert Bitmap to String
    public static String BitMapToString(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        byte[] arr = baos.toByteArray();
        imageData = Base64.encodeToString(arr, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return imageData;
    }

    // Convert String to Bitmap
    public static Bitmap StringToBitMap(String image) {
        try {
            byte[] encodeByte = Base64.decode(image, Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0,
                    encodeByte.length);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Plus one for your work.Great method, even i use the same

Comment: I put String Base64 in web view with HTML format then its work fine, but not work in above code

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `thumbnail.recycle();` after loading bitmap,, either remove it or call before loading bitmap