# Set a bitmap image in ImageView

Tags: java, android, bitmap, imageview, base64

I've tried this

```
try {
        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(repPlus, Base64.URL_SAFE);
        Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Error: ", e.getMessage());
    }
```

And it returns an error:

```
bad base-64
```

And then I've tried this [Bad base-64 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23241257/bad-base-64-error). And it removes the error. And [Base64 to Bitmap to display in ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30964027/base64-to-bitmap-to-display-in-imageview) for decoding a base64 String

```
try {
        String repSlash = product.getImage().replace("/", "_");
        String repPlus = repSlash.replace("+", "-");
        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(repPlus, Base64.URL_SAFE);
        Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Error: ", e.getMessage());
    }
```

But the image does not views in the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this after initializing the *Bitmap* `decodedByte`

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), decodedByte);
holder.imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

**EDIT:** Try this:

```
String base64Image = product.getImage().split(",")[1];

byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(base64Image, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);

holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
```

**Hope this helped!**

Comment: I got a problem with getResources(). I'm in an adapter class. Is this okay?

Comment: Then add a Context variable to the Adapter constructor, and then do like, `BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), decodedByte);`

Comment: I'll post again if I find a solution

Comment: @MikaelFaire Can you recheck your _Base64 String_ because if you're doing the conversion right, this should work. And further, check if the _holder.imageview_ is set up clearly.

Comment: My base64 string is like this "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCE.............."

Comment: I used the imageview by using images in drawable. But by using this data from mysql, using php and json it does not view the image.

Comment: @MikaelFaire Try the updated version. That should work. Or, I think you should recheck the **ImageView**.